# getting duplication in output in mysql query

Tags: mysql

i am having 4 table dat is:

**Question_Paper_Master:** this table contain question id of those question for selected for test(exam).

```
Question_Paper_Id   Question_Id   Test_Id
1                     1              1 
2                     2              1 
3                     3              1 
4                     4              1
```

**Question_Bank:** this table contain list of questions.

```
Question__Id      Question            Question_Type_id
1                     abc               1 
2                     pqr               1 
3                     lmn               1 
4                     xyz               1
```

**Question_Type:** this table contain type for question dat is single choice(radio button) or multiple choice (checkbox).

```
Question__type_id        Question_type     
1                        single choice   
2                        multiple choice
```

**Option_Master:** this table contain list of option for questions.

```
option__Id        Question_id            option
1                     1                    a 
2                     1                    b 
3                     1                    c 
4                     1                    d
.
.
.
```

now problem is i want to fetch option and its type(single or multiple) by question and get output in **datatable**.

My query is as :

```
select q.Question,o.Options,t.Question_Type 
    from Question_Paper_Master Qp,Question_Bank Q,Option_Master o,Question_Type_Master T
    where qp.Question_Id=q.Question_Id and q.Question_Id=o.Question_Id
    and q.Question_Type_Id=t.Question_Type_Id
    and qp.Test_Id=9
```

but output is coming as:

```
question      option      questiontype
 abc           a            singlechoice
 abc           b            single choice
 abc           c            singlechoice
 abc           d            single choice
 pqr           a            singlechoice
 pqr           b            single choice
 pqr           c            singlechoice
 pqr           d            single choice
```

i want output like this:

```
question      option      questiontype
 abc           a           singlechoice
               b
               c
               d
pqr            a            singlechoice
               b
               c
               d
```

Comment: You can not display the way you are expecting mysql, thats not the job of mysql rather its the application level which should take care of this, however all you can do is to use `group_concat(option)` while selecting the data and then `group by question`

Comment: can u show me with the query??      bcz m unaware of this

Comment: `select q.Question , group_concat(o.Options) as Options......qp.Test_Id=9  group by q.Question`

Comment: can u show me the whole query please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT question, `option`, questiontype
FROM (
    SELECT IF(question = @prev_question, '', question) AS question,
           `option`,
           IF(question = @prev_question and question_type = @prev_type, '', question_type) AS questiontype,
           @prev_question := question, @prev_type := question_type
    FROM (select q.Question,o.`Option`,t.Question_Type 
          from Question_Paper_Master Qp,Question_Bank Q,Option_Master o,Question_Type T
          where qp.Question_Id=q.Question_Id and q.Question_Id=o.Question_Id
          and q.Question_Type_Id=t.Question_Type_Id
          ORDER BY question, question_type) x
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_question := null, @prev_type := null) vars
) subq
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fdbcf/6)

Comment: I'm trying to run your query in sqlfiddle, but I'm getting lots of errors because you have different table and column names in the query than you do in the list of tables. There's no `Question_Type_Master` table (it's just `Question_Type`, and there's no `questiontype` column, it's `question_type`. Fixing all these mistakes is driving me crazy.

Comment: `option` is a reserved word, it has to be in backticks. I've corrected all the other naming errors. And I had to remove `test_id = 9` because that's not in the sample data. See the working sqlfiddle.

Comment: bt will this query run in sql server r2?

Comment: I don't know SQL-Server, I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    select case when rank=1 then question else "" end "question",
   `Option`,case when rank=1 then question_type else "" end "type"
    from (
    select q.question,o.`Option`,t.question_type,
    ( 
       CASE question 
       WHEN @curType 
       THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
       ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := question END
   ) + 1 AS rank
   from Question_Paper_Master Qp,Question_Bank Q,Option_Master o,Question_Type T,
   (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r 
   where qp.Question_Id=q.Question_Id and
   q.Question_Id=o.Question_Id
   and q.Question_Type_Id=t.Question_Type_Id
   and qp.Test_Id=1) as t
```

Comment: that condition u have written o.option='a' that is not fixed.option can be anything

Comment: @user3831519 now check it

Comment: lots of error is coming.have u checked in sql fiddle?]